# Error while display pdf-viewer in bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, pdf, bootstrap-4

I am trying to preview pdf, I am using bootstrap modal but I get the following error:

> Unable to initialize viewer TypeError: Cannot read property 'div' of undefined

When I call my modal the pdf does not display in the modal but if I move the scrollbar from left to right, then I can see the pdf in the modal. Has anyone run into the same problem? And what is the best solution to fix that?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="preview{{f.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{ f.name }}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div *ngIf="this['sourceIMG' + f.id]!=null">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" [src]="this['sourceIMG' + f.id]" />
                </div>
                <pdf-viewer [src]="this['sourcePDF' + f.id]"
                            [render-text]="true" [page]="page"
                            [show-all]="true" style="display:block">
                </pdf-viewer>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing issue on github about this problem. The problem happends when you use NgIf to show or hide pdf-viewer.

Please check [This](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/224) and [This](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/367)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. Actually it works fine when i hide it with *ngIf. it only throws error in bootstrap modal.

Comment: in modal, pdf-viewer is initially hidden right? the problem occurs because of this. check the issue you will understand what I mean

Comment: I have already seen it but I am saying it is working without error when I hide with ngIf. That is how I am displaying the preview right now. But i would be nice to put it in a modal.

Comment: can you try with modal but default as initialized. I mean put ngIf=true in your modal to see the behavior